# Reload minor mode in .dir-locals.el

Tags: emacs, text-editors

In .dir-locals.el, I can only set variables to values, I can't call functions. However, after the following code is executed, I need to disable and then re-enable `whitespace-mode`:

```
((nil . ((indent-tabs-mode . t)
     (whitespace-style . (face empty trailing lines-tail)))))
```

I've tried adding `(eval . (global-whitespace-mode))` based on another answer I found, but this completely breaks whitespace mode and then I can't enable or disable it. How do I reload this minor mode?

Comment: `M-x whitespace-mode` is for just that buffer; or, globally `M-x global-whitespace-mode`

Answer (score 5):

I think what you're looking for is to enable `whitespace-mode` for your buffer. You can do that in `.dir-locals.el` but the syntax is not obvious:

```
((nil . ((indent-tabs-mode . t)
         (mode . whitespace)
         (mode . flyspell))))
```

This will enable both `whitespace-mode` and `flyspell-mode`; it works for any minor mode you may want to load that way.